# Group columns into categories and series in SSRS stacked bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, stacked-chart

I need to make a stacked bar chart in SQl Server Reporting Services.
The data however is in a single row:

```
Cat1Act | Cat1Inact | Cat2Act | Cat2Inact | Cat3Act | Cat4Act | Cat4Inact |Cat5Active | Cat5Inactive
52      | 61        | 25      | 55        | 35      | 1       | 4         | 3         | 12
```

This is the desired chart produced via Excel:
[image]

How would I group these columns into the respective categories and series within SSRS?

Comment: Your sample data is not making much sense. Can you post exactly the values that you want to reflect in the chart? I did many charts of same types and I believe I can help you if I know the data.

Comment: Hard to describe in a comment but you need to get your dataset to return 3 columns `(Category, Status, Value)`. The rows you then contains something like `"Cat1", "Active", 50` ;    `"Cat1", "Inactive", 50` ;    `"Cat2", "Active", 22`;     `"Cat2", "Inactive", 56` . After that you can just group by the category.

Comment: @Viking - Appreciate the help. Editied the original post to include the values used to generate the chart. This is how the data exists in the database. However, I feel Alan Schofield is correct and I need to change my query to get the data into an appropriate format.